# Angular-ui-bootstrap-tabs animated transition in but not out

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

I updated an example by user [@austin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1370880/austin)

I'm have an issue when transitioning backwards (ie. tab3 to tab2. forward seems to work fine. Wondered if anyone could see what I was missing.

```
<uib-tabset></uib-tabset>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/UCwylcvBwGh3QmIlSkMQ?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your **ubi-tabset** to `<uib-tabset active="currentTab">`